# Unclear the unclear close?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

For example, see this question, closed because of being unclear: [When can eating fruits give maximum health benefits?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/3704/99)

It is close because of asking for "the best". And as Carey Gregory says in the comment:

> There's that word "best" again. Best health benefits in what way? [...] To make this question answerable you're going to have to define "best" and it's going to need to be a fairly narrow definition.

Many folks go to here and ask such questions. If I'm an asker, I would be irritated if my question gets closed without knowing the reason why. I have tried my best to give the detail, yet it is closed because of being unclear. If I'm a commenter, I would be irritated if I have to take about one topic from time to time.

I suggest to put that quote into the unclear tag. If possible, make a canonical question why there is no best in health, and show them that even outside health topic, asking for the best is still a wrong question (try asking a new question, then type `best` on the title field).

Comment: But what if that's not what makes the question unclear?

Comment: @CareyGregory just say "if you are looking for the best bla bla", then elaborate the reason is enough. I have seen a site doing this, but not remember atm

Comment: now I want to know why you don't like this. Don't you want to avoid repeating a same thing from time to time?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your proposal. You want to change the standard text that gets displayed when a question is closed for being unclear to include what I said. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. What else can it be? What did you think about this first?

Comment: @Ooker - there is in effect a post notice on it saying it's unclear.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Is there? Can you link to me an example? Or making it an answer would be better.

Comment: The yellow-boxed close reason is much like a post notice. If the OP wants to edit, it can be reopened. Reasons for post notices are more suited to answers than questions on this cite, since references aren't necessary for questions, and there's no mandate that they be more than a single sentence.

Answer (score 2):

As Carey Gregory already said in a comment, this cannot be done.

First, this reason covers *all* unclear questions we get. Not only the ones where an asker asks for "best", but also a ton of other types. If we were to edit that into the "unclear" reason, it will be *wrong* for everyone whose question does not mention "best" but is unclear.

Second, there is also a technical reason. These canned texts are the same across the network. A site cannot have them changed for itself. The only changeable part are the three subtypes we can choose when closing something as offtopic. But we are not closing "best" questions for being offtopic, so we cannot use that.

If you think that it needs clarification, please leave such a comment manually when you are voting to close a "best" question.

Comment: I mean the specific reason for the off-topic close, like [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58334/14341) question. Sorry for being... unclear

Comment: This is not an off topic close. It is an unclear close. Unclear closes don't have specific reasons. Neither does any other close. Only off topic has them.

Comment: I see. So how about a post notice?